# Adding a property to an Angular object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am running an Angular app that pulls its data from a Web API service. The API returns the objects as JSON and the Angular service (via $http.get() ) returns them to the controller as an array of objects. Pretty normal stuff.

What I'd like to do is add a property to each of the returned objects called "Selected". This property is purely for GUI purposes (is the object selected or not in the UI) and doesn't need to be persisted in any way. I figured the easiest thing to do was loop through the returned array of objects and just add it. So my code looks like this:

```
function getData() {
    myService.getData()
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.myData = data.results;
            // Add a "Selected" property to each object
            $.each($scope.myData, function(item) {
                item.Selected = false;
            });
}
```

When it gets to the line that says, "item.Selected = false" it throw an error message, saying "Cannot assign to read-only property Selected".

It is unclear to me why "Selected" is read-only? I didn't know if maybe Angular does some funky object processing when it reads data? What am I doing wrong here? Or should I be approaching this a completely different way?

Note (I'd like to avoid having to make Selected a part of the original object, as it's not representative of anything related to that object).

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct data? When using `strict mode` *(which I hope you are)*, trying to assign a property to a primitive value (such as a string or a boolean) will throw this error.

Comment: Can you confirm that after assigning `$scope.myData = data.results;`, `$scope.myData` is indeed the expected array?

Comment: If you're using selected in the UI only and always defaulting to false, why set it at all? Just set it to true when it is selected and false when unselected.

Comment: Not an answer, but I want to share the pattern I use to handle adding view-specific properties to data fetched from the server. Example: assume you have are receiving and array of user entities. Then create a `User` Model class that expects the user entity object in the constructor and exposes it via an `entity` property from which the original properties can be referenced. Then extend via `Prototype' with any additional properties. Similar approach: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc

Comment: Regarding the data, here is a screenshot showing an inspector which visualizes the data, and the error being thrown. http://screencast.com/t/LMpFMTAztTo

Comment: Check your usage of $.each, first param it returns when going through an array is the index, second is the item. Index is int, which is what won't allow an added property. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback

Comment: Bryant, while I'm not 100% sure what's going on with the property, your answer is actually the one that works for me, which is - just don't do that. Not setting a default value is working fine for me, and now the UI is working as designed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to add property to an object use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/),

"each _.each(list, iteratee, [context]) Alias: forEach 
Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iteratee function. The iteratee is bound to the context object, if one is passed. Each invocation of iteratee is called with three arguments: (element, index, list). If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's arguments will be (value, key, list). Returns the list for chaining."

"extend _.extend(destination, *sources) 
Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, and return the destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will override properties of the same name in previous arguments."

```
$scope.myData = data.results;
// Add a "Selected" property to each object   

_.each($scope.myData, function(ent) {
    _.extend(ent, {
        Selected : false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/LMpFMTAztTo) actually gives you a more useful error message than what you posted (emphasis mine):

> Cannot assign to read only property 'Selected' **of 0**

This shows that instead of the object, you're getting a number as your `item` variable (0 in this case). Assigning properties to primitives in strict mode throws this "Cannot assign to read-only property" error. *(Without strict mode, it just fails silently.)*

As [JcT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446030/jct) pointed out in a comment, this is because `$.each` calls the function with 2 params passed, the index first, the value second. See the [documentation of `$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> **callback**
>
> Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )

So even though you named your parameter `item`, it received the value of the current index instead. This means your code can be fixed by just adding this missing first parameter to your callback, like this:

```
function getData() {
    myService.getData()
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.myData = data.results;
            // Add a "Selected" property to each object
            $.each($scope.myData, function(index, item) { //index was added here!
                item.Selected = false;
            });
}
```